# Client not receiving emails from page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I'm currently working on my first website for a client, thus completely new to PHP. The page is online, however the email form seems to do nothing but refresh the page. I put a conditional at the end of the php file to echo success or fail, but it seems to do nothing. I can't pinpoint where I'm going wrong.

html

```
   <form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
    <p> <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" required> 
    </p>
    <p> <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName" required> </p>
    <p> <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phoneNumber" required> 
    </p>
    <p> <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email_address" id="emailAddress" 
     required> </p>
    <p class="full"> <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" rows="5" id="message" required> 
    </textarea> </p>
    <p class="full">
    <button id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form"><span 
    id="status"></span>Email</button>
    </p>
    </form>
```

JS

```
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
    _("button").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "name", _("name").value );
  formdata.append( "lastName", _("lastName").value );
    formdata.append( "phoneNumber", _("phoneNumber").value );
  formdata.append( "emailAddress", _("emailAddress").value );
  formdata.append( "message", _("message").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "index.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thank you '+_("name").value +', your message has been sent.</h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("button").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['phoneNumber']) && isset($_POST['emailAddress']) && isset($_POST['message']) ){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
  $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    $message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
    $to = "info@glaucomaspecialists.com";
    $from = $emailAddress;
    $subject = 'Schedule Inquiry';
    $message = "<b>Name:</b> '.$name.' <b>LastName:</b> '.$lastName.' <br><b>Phone:</b> '.$phoneNumber' <b>Email:</b> '.$emailAddress.' <p>'.$message.'</p>";
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to narrow this down to a server side or client side issue

Comment: Is your JS code even executing? A button of type="submit" will submit the form which will "refresh" the page without executing the Javascript.

Comment: It looks like you are not meeting the `IF` conditions at all so nothing within is being executed. Let's see how everything is going through to the backend by placing the following in the very first line: `print "<PRE>".print_r($_POST[])."</PRE>";` and share the output with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working backwards through your code - if your test echo statement isn't writing anything from an if/else then it is never getting executed.  This can only be because your statement isn't evaluating as true:

```
isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['phoneNumber']) && isset($_POST['emailAddress']) && isset($_POST['message']) ){
```

So either your AJAX isn't sending any data at all, or there is a mistake in your name values.  Looking through your code your HTML states

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" required>
```

Whilst your JS says

```
formdata.append( "name", _("name").value );
```

You've swapped from using `firstName` and `name` as your id.

Therefore

```
isset($_POST['name'])
```

Evaluates to false and your code is never run.

Comment: Smacking my forehead. Ok, I've made that correction and now the page is not refreshing but the button just remains with the 'please wait' message. In the console it throws an error with 
main.js:33 POST https://glaucomaspecialistsofsanfrancisco.com/index.php 404 ()
submitForm @ main.js:33
onsubmit @ (index):200.

Comment: 404 means the function can’t find index.php. Is that definitely what the php file is called? Is it in the same directory as the file with the form?